# How to interpolate styles in React?

Tags: reactjs, styles

I want to color-code words by language in my React app. I have a `styles` file, which contains things like:

```
english: {
  // style here
}

french: {
  // style here
}

spanish: {
  // style here
}

// etc.
```

Each of my words (`entrys`) is an object that contains a `language` key/value pair, i.e. `{language: french}`.

I *could* create a long `case/switch` statement, but I'm looking for a shorter way. Here's my `case/switch` statement:

```
var color;

switch (entry.language) {
  case 'english':
    color = styles.english;
    break;
  case 'french':
    color = styles.french;
    break;
// etc.

<div style={color}> {entry.word} </div>
```

That seems unnecessarily repetitive, especially if I have a lot of languages. Instead, I want to be able to just interpolate `entry.language` into my `div`, something like:

```
<div style={styles.{entry.language}} {entry.word} </div>
```

That doesn't work. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to access an object. The bracket notation is what you need

```
<div style={styles[entry.language]} >{entry.word} </div>
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I stumble on this page with a similar question but ended up finding the answer
from https://medium.com/capital-one-developers/cut-the-sass-how-to-use-inline-javascript-styles-for-everything-f5ac5b77ae57

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, css } from 'aphrodite';
import { brandRed } from './colors'; 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
  foo: { 
    border: `1px solid ${brandRed}`,
  },
});

const UserMenu = () => (
  <div className={css(style.foo)}>
    This box has a nice border.
  </div>
);
```